# Windows Phone 7 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7

Where can I find the SDK for new Windows Phone 7?

Comment: Did you contact Microsoft?  What did they say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of more resources:

- [Windows Phone 7 Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ca23285f-bab8-47fa-b364-11553e076a9a)
- [Silverlight.net learn videos for Windows Phone 7](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/windows-phone/)
- [Programming for Windows Phone 7 ebook by Charles Petzold](http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoft_press/archive/2010/03/15/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-series-draft-preview.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:** As the no-commenting-down-voter reminded me, these steps are no longer required as the installer now includes everything you need.

In addition to Rowland's answer, you'll need a few things installed in order to use Blend (for Silverlight animations):

- [Expression Blend 4 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6f014e07-0053-4aca-84a7-cd82f9aa989f&displaylang=en)
- [Microsoft Expression Blend Add-in Preview for Windows Phone](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=47f5c718-9dec-4557-9687-619c0fdd3d4f&displaylang=en)
- [Microsoft Expression Blend SDK Preview for Windows Phone](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=86370108-4c14-42ee-8855-226e5dd9b85b)

Here are some other resources you might find useful:

- [Windows Phone Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535(v=VS.92).aspx) on MSDN
- [Windows Phone Class Library Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff403118(v=VS.92).aspx)
- [Code Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=VS.92).aspx) (not included with the SDK download; rather limited, but a good place to bookmark)

Answer (score 2):

It hasn't been officially released as of yet. I heard it would be detailed at MIX.

Comment: The SDK has now been officially released and can be found at http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series/.  This answer should be updated.

Answer (score 2):

A community Tech Preview of the tools is available through the [Windows Mobile Developer website](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series/)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the new released SDK at the [Windows Phone for Developers homepage](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series/).

Click the "Download the Developer Tools" link on the right hand side.

It includes a specialized version of Visual Studio 2010 Express and a device emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the windows phone SDK can be found on Microsoft's website here: 
http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started