# Develop for Windows Phone with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Are there some resources where one can learn how to develop for Windows Phone using Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400944/windows-phone-7-sdk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows Mobile is basically dead - however, if you are referring to Windows Phone (which is replacing Windows Mobile), then yes, you can download, today, [Microsoft Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone (CTP)](http://www.microsoft.com/express/phone/).

For resources on learning how to develop, there is a [Developer Site for Windows Phone (http://developer.windowsphone.com/)](http://developer.windowsphone.com/).

Comment: Windows Mobile is far from dead.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the new Windows Phone.

Answer (score 3):

If you are already familiar with C# development, Charles Petzold will be releasing a free e-book on programming for Windows Phone 7. That should be the main resource you will need, most of it is already available online: http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Yep, in addition to Reed's answers, if you're talking about Windows Phone 7 Series in particular, the info is [here](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series) ([developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series)).

Also, even if you have Visual Studio 2010 Pro, you'll need to download their whole package, including VS2010 Express to use the new SDK.

Furthermore, unfortunately you can't have any other versions of VS installed on the machine you want to try the SDK on, so you'd be better using a different box, or a virtual machine.

have fun!

### Correction

My bad, as Arun Mahapatra points out below, you can run VS2010 express with the phone SDK along with other versions of VS, with only a few caveats.

Comment: So you HAVE to reinstall VS2010 Express to develop for Windows Phone 7? Do I have to uninstall my current version of VS2010 and install VS2010 Express CTP? Or does the CTP version automatically uninstall VS2010. Also will I still be able to program in C#, WPF and Winforms? Or is the CTP version ONLY for Windows Phone?

Comment: You can install and use VS 2010 Phone Express side by side with other versions of VS (including 2008 or any version of VS 2010 RC). 

If you have VS 2010 Beta version, you need to upgrade it to RC and then use it with VS2010 Express. It will not automatically uninstall VS 2010. 

With VS 2010 phone express you can only program for phones. You will need to install VS 2010 RC along with it to be able to program in C#, WPF etc. for desktop. More details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428633(VS.92).aspx

Comment: So bottom line, if I have VS10RTM Ultimate on my machine, what steps should I take to start develop WP7?